# How to pass StartupEventArgs to other ViewModels in Prism application

Tags: wpf, prism

We are using Prism 7. Are there any best practices to pass StartupEventArg parameters obtained
from the Prism OnStartup method of App.xaml.cs to other ViewModels. The Event Aggregator is not available in this method so it looks like we can't use this method of passing data to viewmodels.

Thanks

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        if (e.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(e.Args[0]);
            var result = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
            var username = result["username"];
            var password = result["password"];
           // how to get these to viewmodels
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get these to viewmodels?

You create a service that provides the raw arguments to anyone interested, most likely another service that parses them into user name and password.

Example:

```
internal class EnvironmentCommandLineArgumentsProvider : ICommandLineArgumentsProvider
{
    #region ICommandLineArgumentsProvider
    public IReadOnlyList<string> Arguments => _arguments.Value;
    #endregion

    #region private
    private readonly Lazy<IReadOnlyList<string>> _arguments = new Lazy<IReadOnlyList<string>>( () => Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() );
    #endregion
}

internal class CommandLineInitialCredentialsProvider : IInitialCredentialsProvider
{
    public CommandLineInitialCredentialsProvider( ICommandLineArgumentsProvider commandLineArgumentsProvider )
    {
        _credentials = new Lazy<(string UserName, string Password)>( () =>
        {
            if (commandLineArgumentsProvider.Arguments.Count > 0)
            {
                var builder = new UriBuilder(commandLineArgumentsProvider.Arguments[0]);
                var result = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
                return (result["username"], result["password"]);
            }
            return (null, null);
        });
    }

    #region IInitialCredentialsProvider
    public string UserName => _credentials.Value.UserName;
    public string Password => _credentials.Value.Password;
    #endregion

    #region private
    private readonly Lazy<(string UserName, string Password)> _credentials;
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about Environment.GetCommandLineArgs